# How to store the result of a command expression in a variable using bat scripts?

Tags: batch-file

I have the command below to count all directories that that follow the pattern `20??????` :

```
'dir /b "20??????" | find /c "2"'
```

For example, if I have the following directories, the command would return 6:

```
20090901
20090902
20090903
20090904
20090905
20090906
```

How can I store the result of this command (6 in the forementioned example) in a variable?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
set cmd="dir /b "20??????" | find /c "2" "

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (' %cmd% ') DO SET X=%%i
```

Comment: Just a note for others who may be using this: if this is done inside a batch file, `%i` must be replaced with `%%i` both times in the `for` command.

Comment: @fduff It is indeed a wonder that assignment of command result to a variable is accomplished using `FOR`.

Comment: Uh, this doesn't work for multi-line output with spaces it seems?

Comment: @CamiloMartin Agreed, that snippet is likely not able to capture multi-line output. I no longer have a Windows machine (virtual or otherwise) with which I could attempt an improved solution.  Sorry.

Comment: @CamiloMartin Sorry for the double comment, I accidentally pressed Enter.  Also I apparently struggle at linebreaks.

`FOR /F "tokens=*" %i IN (' %cmd% ') DO SET X=%i`

Additional uses of the tokens command, such as cutting out the second column:

`FOR /F "tokens=1,3*" %i IN (' %cmd% ') DO SET X=%i %j %k`

That's i equals column one, j equals column 3, and k equals columns 4 and on.  It does assume that the delimiter is a space (in the SET section), so modify that if need be (you can define your delims the same same way you define tokens).

The question mark is your friend!
`FOR /?`

Comment: @Derek good to know! By the way, for a short while (I think a few minutes) StackOverflow will let you edit a comment, It's useful also when you want to undo a typo, but it only lasts for a little while after the comment was posted.

Comment: See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/07/31/10334556.aspx) for an explanation of this technique.

Comment: @CamiloMartin I *think* I made this answer a community wiki. I'm unsure if such an action is subject to moderation (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183). Anyway, I'm hoping you have sufficient reputation to improve upon the answer. Cheers!

Comment: @Derek Comments to CamiloMartin apply equally to you (apologies, apparently SO comment UI limitation permits only one @ reference).

Comment: Can I donate this answer to someone who currently writes BAT scripts?

Answer (score 9):

```
(dir /b "20??????" | find /c "2")>>x.txt  
set /p variable=<x.txt
```

That's all.

Of course, if you don't want the file, just do this afterwards:

```
del x.txt
```

**EDIT** -- How to make the filename unique:

@Mai: use this to create a uniqe file name:

```
set timestamp=%date:.=%%time::=%
set timestamp=%timestamp:,=%
set timestamp=%timestamp:/=%
set timestamp=%timestamp:-=%
set filename=file%timestamp%.tmp
```

Add more replacements if the date format of your system culture has other characters inside

Comment: So, what if there is already a file named x.txt? (Created by user, or other programs?)

Comment: @Mai: I added the code to create unique file names.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample:

```
@echo off
set wildcard=C:\*.*
set count=0
FOR /F %%a in ('DIR /B %wildcard%') do set /A count=count+1
echo %count% files matching %wildcard%
set choice=
set /p choice=Press enter to continue ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
@echo off
set com=echo HI
::Start Of Code You Need
echo|%com%>>"%temp%\tmp.txt"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (%temp%\tmp.txt) do (
set output=%%x
)
del /q %temp%\tmp.txt
::End Of Code You Need
echo This Is The Output:
echo %output%
pause>NUL
```

It takes the input from `com` and outputs from `output`

Answer (score -2):

```
@echo off

REM The command fltmc volumes provides some information about drives
REM I need to extract the drive letter associated to a particular volume name.
REM Here's how:

fltmc volumes | find /i "\Device\HarddiskVolume3" > delme.txt
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%i in (delme.txt) DO echo %%i
Del /f delme.txt
```