# Add new line in text file with Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, newline, stdout

I have a text file which has more than 200 lines in it, and I just want to add a new line before line 4. I'm using Windows XP.

Example text file before input:

```
header 1
header 2
header 3
details 1
details 2
```

After output:

```
header 1
header 2
header 3
<----- This is new line ---->
details 1
details 2
```

Comment: I don't think the accepted answer is correct here. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31934142/4294399

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I believe you are using the

```
echo Text >> Example.txt
```

function?

If so the answer would be simply adding a "." (Dot) directly after the echo with nothing else there.

Example:

```
echo Blah
echo Blah 2
echo. #New line is added
echo Next Blah
```

Comment: thanks your reply james Dyson.
i need to edit the existing file instead of new file

Comment: using the `>>` to direct the output to file will append to the end of the file. If you use a single chevron then the output will overwrite the existing file if it does exist, or create a new file if it does not.

Comment: I'm not really sure how this answers the question. It seems the text file already exists and the OP just wanted to insert a new line in the middle somewhere, not the end.

Answer (score 4):

*DISCLAIMER: The below solution does not preserve trailing tabs.*

---

If you know the exact number of lines in the text file, try the following method:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET origfile=original file
SET tempfile=temporary file
SET insertbefore=4
SET totallines=200
<%origfile% (FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,%totallines%) DO (
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  SET /P L=
  IF %%i==%insertbefore% ECHO(
  ECHO(!L!
  ENDLOCAL
)
) >%tempfile%
COPY /Y %tempfile% %origfile% >NUL
DEL %tempfile%
```

The loop reads lines from the original file one by one and outputs them. The output is redirected to a temporary file. When a certain line is reached, an empty line is output before it.

After finishing, the original file is deleted and the temporary one gets assigned the original name.

---

**UPDATE**

If the number of lines is unknown beforehand, you can use the following method to obtain it:

```
FOR /F %%C IN ('FIND /C /V "" ^<%origfile%') DO SET totallines=%%C
```

(This line simply replaces the `SET totallines=200` line in the above script.)

The method has one tiny flaw: if the file ends with an empty line, the result will be the actual number of lines minus one. If you need a workaround (or just want to play safe), you can use the method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664761/how-to-count-no-of-lines-in-text-file-and-store-the-value-into-a-variable-using-b/5665718#5665718).

Comment: 1) this script i save as run1.bat. i test to run it, got error msg (the syntax of command is incorrect.) the file rename as after.txt

Comment: 2) the format is out of order <br/>
for example:

input 
header 1<--here got tab delimited format--><--here got tab delimited format--> 
header 2<--here got tab delimited format--><--here got tab delimited format-->
header 3<--here got tab delimited format--><--here got tab delimited format-->
details 1
details 2 

output: 
header 1<--tab delimited is missing--><--tab delimited is missing--> 
header 2<--tab delimited is missing--><--tab delimited is missing-->
header 3<--tab delimited is missing--><--tab delimited is missing-->

details 1
details 2 </pre>

Comment: I tested the script too and didn't get any errors. As for your issue #2... Well, using a batch script to process a file with such tender contents is like mowing a lawn with a combine harvester: it *might* be possible, but requires **very** thorough adjustments. I re-tested the script and it indeed removes trailing tab characters. So far I have no idea how to work around that. Someone else might. Or maybe you should consider using other tools. You could also try your luck at [superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: item 1 - still have error
this is the script.

@ECHO OFF <br>
SET origfile="C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\test1\before.txt" <br>
SET tempfile="C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\test1\after.txt" <br>
SET insertbefore=4 <br>
FOR /F %%C IN ('FIND /C /V "" ^<%origfile%') DO SET totallines=%%C <br>

<%origfile% (FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,%totallines%) DO ( <br>
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion <br>
  SET /P L= <br>
  IF %%i==%insertbefore% ECHO( <br>
  ECHO(!L! <br>
  ENDLOCAL <br>
)<br>
) >%tempfile% <br>
DEL %origfile% <br>
RENAME %tempfile% %origfile% <br>
pause <br>

Comment: I see now, thanks. Please change the last two lines of the script like in my updated answer. The problem was, the second argument of the RENAME command should be just a name, with no path.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
type text1.txt >> combine.txt
echo >> combine.txt
type text2.txt >> combine.txt
```

or something like this:

```
echo blah >> combine.txt
echo blah2 >> combine.txt
echo >> combine.txt
echo other >> combine.txt
```

Comment: This won't work in Windows because the echo command with nothing following it actually prints the echo state, "ECHO is ON" for example.

Comment: Though it is an old post, if someone wants to use this solution in windows, please use _echo. >> combine.txt_. The additional "dot" after echo should solve the "ECHO is ON" problem.

Comment: @Saneeshkumar you should make that into an answer.

Answer (score -2):

Suppose you want to insert a particular line of text (not an empty line):

```
@echo off
FOR /F %%C IN ('FIND /C /V "" ^<%origfile%') DO SET totallines=%%C
set /a totallines+=1

@echo off
<%origfile% (FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,%totallines%) DO (
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  SET /p L=
  IF %%i==%insertat% ECHO(!TL!
  ECHO(!L!
  ENDLOCAL
)
) >%tempfile%

COPY /Y %tempfile% %origfile% >NUL

DEL %tempfile%
```