# Add Text To A Certain Line In A Text File With Batch

Tags: file, batch-file

Is it possible to have a command used in a batch file to append to a text file and add text on a certain Line in the txt file?

> Txt File:
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   5

Is it possible to add a new line and put 4 between 3 and 5?

Comment: Will it always be the fourth line, or will it be the line between the values "3" and "5" regardless of where they are located?

Comment: It Does Not Matter, I Just Want To Know How To Do It.

Comment: Actually, it's extremely important. If it's always the fourth line, you'd use a `for /F` loop with the `skip` option. If it's based on line content, you're going to use `find /n` and a `for /L` loop.

Comment: Ok. Let's do if it's always the fourth Line Then.

Comment: Note that `for /F` skips empty lines, so such will get lost.

Answer (score 2):

This answer will add a `4` between a `3` and a `5`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
ren in.txt in.tmp
set p=
for /f %%a in (in.tmp) do (
  if "%%a"=="5" if "!p!"=="3" Echo 4 >> in.txt
  Echo %%a >>in.txt
  set p=%%a
)
del in.tmp
```