# Count the number of lines of each text file in a given directory and store it in a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to count the number of lines of each text file in a given directory and store them in a variable.

Here is my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /R "temp\textpipe_tmp\" %%U in (*.txt) DO (
    set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" "%%U" | find /C ":""
    for /f %%a in ('!cmd!') do set number=%%a
    echo %number%
)

:eof
pause
```

I'm not sure why it does not work but if I get rid of SET, it works:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /R "temp\textpipe_tmp\" %%U in (*.txt) DO (
    findstr /R /N "^" "%%U" | find /C ":"
)

:eof
pause
```

I need the result stored in a variable.

Comment: Simpler and faster method: `find /v /c "" filename.ext`, see [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9473079/3959875). Also with delayed expansion use `!number!`, not `%number%`

Comment: Thanks. That delayed expansion thing was the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another version, which does the same thing but is slightly better readable:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /R "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\ICT" %%U in (*.txt) DO (
    set lines=0
    for /f  %%A in (%%U) do (set /a lines+=1)
    echo !lines!
)
pause
```

Comment: Remember that `for /F` ignores empty lines, and also lines starting with `;` (unless you change the default option `eol=;`)...

Answer (score 0):

As @wOxxOm stated in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891859/count-the-number-of-lines-of-each-text-file-in-a-given-directory-and-store-them#comment55547042_33891859), `find` is the perfect choice for this task.

Supposing there is a file `test.txt` containing 12 lines, `find /V /C "" "C:test.txt"` will output something like:

> ```
> ---------- C:TEST.TXT: 12
> ```

So let us use a `for /F` loop to capture such an output and string substitution to get the text portion after `:`<kbd>SPACE</kbd>:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R "temp\textpipe_tmp\" %%U in ("*.txt") do (
    rem capturing the output of `find` here:
    for /F "delims=" %%A in ('find /V /C "" "%%~U"') do (
        set "NUMBER=%%~A"
        rem substituting substring `: ` and everything before by nothing:
        set "NUMBER=!NUMBER:*: =!"
    )
    rem at this point, variable `NUMBER` is available
    rem for the currently processed file in `%%~U`:
    echo !NUMBER!
)
endlocal
```

Note that `find /V /C ""` will return unexpected reslts if there are empty lines at the *end* of the file (one of such might not be included in the count). However, empty lines at the beginning or in between non-empty ones will be counted.

---

#### Update:

Using redirection like `> "C:test.txt" find /V /C ""` rather than `find /V /C "" "C:test.txt"` avoids the prefix `---------- C:TEST.TXT:` and just returns the number of lines (like `12`). With this modification no string substitution is necessary and so the code looks like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R "temp\textpipe_tmp\" %%U in ("*.txt") do (
    rem capturing the output of `find` here:
    for /F "delims=" %%A in ('^> "%%~U" find /V /C ""') do (
        set "NUMBER=%%~A"
    )
    rem at this point, variable `NUMBER` is available
    rem for the currently processed file in `%%~U`:
    echo !NUMBER!
)
endlocal
```

The redirection mark `<` needs to be escaped like `^<` when being used after `in` in `for /F`.