# CMake: How to call execute_process with a double quote in the argument? a.k.a. Using find from CMake to count lines matching a string

Tags: windows, cmake, find, findstr

I will like to call the command [`find`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725655.aspx) from within a [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/execute_process.html).

The format of the `find` command is:

```
find [/v] [/c] [/n] [/i] [/off[line]] "<String>" [[<Drive>:][<Path>]<FileName>[...]]
```

So, the string has to be double quoted. However, if in cmake I do:

```
execute_process(COMMAND <firstCommandPipingSomethingToFind> 
                COMMAND find "<myString>" /c
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE MY_COUNT
                OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
```

I get an error `FIND: Parameter format not correct`.
If I escape the double quotes with `\`, I get an error `Access denied - \`.
Also using double escaping `\\` or double double quotes `""` does not help.

So my question is:
**Is there a way to escape the double quotes when calling `execute_process` so that `find` receives correctly its argument?**

I could use [`findstr`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx), which doesn't need the double quotes; however it doesn't provide a counting feature. I could use `find` by calling [`find /v /c ""`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23532370/2436175), but again, I need double quotes!
And I would like to count the output lines outside cmake, and store directly the result in `MY_COUNT` variable.

Note: I am using [CMake 3.4.1](http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/user/74)

---

To reproduce the problem you can use the following code, in which `cmake -E echo` is used to feed a string to `findstr` and `find`:

```
#This works
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo hello COMMAND findstr ell OUTPUT_VARIABLE DUMMY)
message (STATUS "0) DUMMY=${DUMMY}")

#All of the following don't work
set(MyCommand "find \"ell\" /c")
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo hello COMMAND "${MyCommand}" OUTPUT_VARIABLE DUMMY)
message (STATUS MyCommand=${MyCommand})
message (STATUS "1) DUMMY=${DUMMY}")

execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo hello COMMAND ${MyCommand} OUTPUT_VARIABLE DUMMY)
message (STATUS "2) DUMMY=${DUMMY}")

execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo hello COMMAND MyCommand OUTPUT_VARIABLE DUMMY)
message (STATUS "3) DUMMY=${DUMMY}")

execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo hello COMMAND "find \"ell\" /c" OUTPUT_VARIABLE DUMMY)
message (STATUS "4) DUMMY=${DUMMY}")
```

Which outputs:

```
0) DUMMY=hello

MyCommand=find "ell" /c
1) DUMMY=
2) DUMMY=
3) DUMMY=
4) DUMMY=
```

---

I also tried

```
set(MyArgument "\"ell\" /c")
message (STATUS MyArgument=${MyArgument})
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo hello COMMAND find "${MyArgument}" OUTPUT_VARIABLE DUMMY)
message (STATUS "1) DUMMY=${DUMMY}")

execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo hello COMMAND find ${MyArgument} OUTPUT_VARIABLE DUMMY)
message (STATUS "2) DUMMY=${DUMMY}")

set(MyArgument "\"ell\"")
message (STATUS MyArgument=${MyArgument})
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo hello COMMAND find "${MyArgument}" /c OUTPUT_VARIABLE DUMMY)
message (STATUS "1) DUMMY=${DUMMY}")

execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo hello COMMAND find ${MyArgument} /c OUTPUT_VARIABLE DUMMY)
message (STATUS "2) DUMMY=${DUMMY}")
```

Which outputs:

```
MyArgument="ell" /c
File not found - \ELL\

1) DUMMY=
File not found - \ELL\

2) DUMMY=
MyArgument="ell"
Access denied - \

1) DUMMY=
Access denied - \

2) DUMMY=
CMake Error at CMakeRules.cmake:404 (execute_process):
  execute_process given COMMAND argument with no value.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:24 (include)
```

The problem persists also if a remove the `/c` option.

---

This:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo hello COMMAND find \"ell\" OUTPUT_VARIABLE DUMMY)
message (STATUS "DUMMY=${DUMMY}")
```

outputs this:

```
Access denied - \

DUMMY=
```

---

Following Tsyvarev suggestion to retrieve which string is effectively passed to the command line, this:

```
execute_process(COMMAND cmd /c echo \"ell\")
execute_process(COMMAND cmd /c echo "ell")
execute_process(COMMAND cmd /c echo ""ell"")
```

outputs this:

```
\"ell\"

ell

"" ell\"\"
```

With a warning for the third command:

```
Argument not separated from preceding token by whitespace.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

Comment: Hmm, escape sequence `\"` is successfully interpreted as `"` for me on Linux. According to [execute_process documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/execute_process.html), `CMake executes the child process using operating system APIs directly. All arguments are passed VERBATIM to the child process. No intermediate shell is used`, so this behaviour shouldn't differ on different OS. What **exact** string do your want to find, and what exact escaping do you tried? (At least, with `\"` escaping, character `\\` should be consumed by CMake).

Comment: Oh, `COMMAND find \"ell\" /c` should work. Taking string from CMake variable is another story: `set(MyArgument "ell")`, `COMMAND find "\"${MyArgument}\"" /c` (outer quotes are optional; they are required only if your string contains spaces). Storing quotes in the variable itself is a bit more complex.. but are you sure you want that?

Comment: Really weird: character "\" should be consumed by CMake interpreter and shouldn't be passed to the command, but "Access denied - \"... Looks like CMake has tried to escape things (which it shouldn't do), and does that incorrectly. What CMake version do you use?

Comment: BTW, using `COMMAND cmd /c echo <string>` you can see exact parameters, passed to the command. Interesting, what it would print in the last case.

Comment: Probably one has to have a look into the sources of CMake. Or file a bug report.

Comment: (from bugreport you refers) `The CreateProcess API on windows does not handle individual arguments but rather requires a single continuous string for the entire command.` - this explains a lot. **But!** `find` command correctly parses quotes given in the windows command line. So there should be a way to pass them via `CreateProcess` too. Looks like a bug in CMake, but it differs from one you refer (`execute_process` calls `CreateProcess` directly, but `add_custom_command`, described in the bugreport, runs shell).

Comment: If you are familiar with Windows programming, you may try to create example on C(or similar) which calls `find` via `CreateProcess` and pass quoted arguments to it. If you succeed with it, then you can fill new bug for CMake.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have posted an answer with a working workaround suggested by CMake developpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to CMake developers](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15898#c40310),
Windows's `find` cannot be called *directly* by cmake from within `execute_process`, because of a limitation of the CreateProcess API and of the non-standard way `find` parses arguments.

It can be called *indirectly* though, by creating a temporary batch script.

My problem of counting occurrences of a string from the output of a program in Windows is solved in the following way:

```
file(WRITE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/countLines.bat [[@find /v /c "" %1]])
execute_process(COMMAND <firstCommandPipingSomethingToFind> COMMAND findstr <regular expression> COMMAND countLines.bat WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} OUTPUT_VARIABLE N_MATCHES OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
message(STATUS "N_MATCHES=${N_MATCHES}")
file(REMOVE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/countLines.bat)
```

The advantage of `findstr` in between is that it supports regular expressions. `find` is only used to [count matching lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664761/how-to-count-no-of-lines-in-text-file-and-store-the-value-into-a-variable-using/23532370#23532370).

The `@` in front of `find` is to prevent the command invocation within the script from ending up in the output variable.