# Find and move files with extension at build time using CMake

Tags: windows, cmake, gcov, gcovr

I'm currently trying to use Gcov and Gcovr from CMake on Windows using MinGW.
Compiling the files with the right flags works like a charm.
However, CLion uses an out-of-source build which Gcov does not understand.

On Linux I used the following to copy all the `*.gcda` and `*.gcno` to the `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` from `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` subfolders:

```
set(GCOV_DATA_DIR  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/gcov_data")
add_custom_target(prepare_coverage
    # Copy necessary files to CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${GCOV_DATA_DIR}
    COMMAND find ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} -name \"*.gcda\" -o -name \"*.gcno\" | xargs -l -i cp {} "${GCOV_DATA_DIR}"
)
```

Note that test binaries are executed in `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`.
This works pretty well and I can call Gcovr with some additional flags afterwards to get a nice report.

However, on Windows I do not have `xargs` (I was already supprised that `find` did work).
To make this CMake command platform-independent I'm looking for a way to make CMake find and copy/move the files during build time (similar to making the directory).

Can anyone tell me if this is possible and how I should do this?
Of course I can always install additional programs or scripts, but I'd rather solve this within CMake instead of having to instruct all the developers to install different tools.

Comment: Regarding `find` and `cmake`, please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34995590/2436175). The fact that you can use `find` like that make me think that you have something like [msys](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys) installed.

Comment: As I mentioned I'm using MinGW. I also have the MSYS packages installed.

Comment: As you can see in my comment on the accepted answer, I have a solution that involves standard Windows tools now.

Comment: The question is already answered. "Shipping it with your project" is the solution I used.

Comment: Maybe the problem can be addressed in a cleaner way. There is a [guide on cmake website](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CTest:Coverage), and also this [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116488/detailed-guide-on-using-gcov-with-cmake-cdash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_PATH` in your project, then `.gcda` and `.gcno` files are created in the directory with executable, so you may compute this directory with `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:tgt>` [generator-expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html).

Because you know names of source files, you may compute absolute paths of all gcov-related files, and generate appropriate copiing commands without `find`.

Another approach could be writting xargs-like program/script by yourself, *shipping it with your project*, and using it in `COMMAND`. So

> ... but I'd rather solve this within CMake instead of having to instruct all the developers to install different tools.

wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Ended up using a batch file and a bash file (selected based on the host OS) that is called during the build.
In batch it's not too hard too accomplish the behavior I wanted and the bash file basically contains what I mentioned in my question.