# CMake: What formatting does execute_process() do?

Tags: c++, powershell, cmd, cmake

I need to call the findstr Windows command (grep on Linux) from my CMakeList.txt.
If I do this, it is working :

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND findstr "NABO_VERSION " nabo\\nabo.h
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    RESULT_VARIABLE FINDSTR_RESULT
    ERROR_VARIABLE FINDSTR_ERROR
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE FINDSTR_OUT
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
```

I get the output:

```
FINDSTR_ERROR =
FINDSTR_OUT =   
  #define NABO_VERSION "1.0.7"
  #define NABO_VERSION_INT 10007
FINDSTR_RESULT = 0
```

However, the space at the end of `"NABO_VERSION "` is not taken into account. I have to add `/c:` before my string.

So I get this following code :

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND findstr /c:"NABO_VERSION " nabo\\nabo.h
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    RESULT_VARIABLE FINDSTR_RESULT
    ERROR_VARIABLE FINDSTR_ERROR
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE FINDSTR_OUT
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
```

But now it doesn't work and I get this:

```
FINDSTR_ERROR =
FINDSTR_OUT =
FINDSTR_RESULT = 1
```

**The command works well in PowerShell or CMD, but not from CMake. I think that CMake modify the command, but in what way ?**

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905194/cmake-how-to-call-execute-process-with-a-double-quote-in-the-argument-a-k-a-u. Passing literal double quotes via `execute_process` to some Windows commands could be difficult (or even impossible). It could be simpler to write a separate shell script and run that script via `execute_process`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I created a test file called `nabo\nabo.h` with the following contents:

```
#define NABO_VERSION "1.0.7"
#define NABO_VERSION_INT 10007
```

Then at cmd, I wrote:

```
> findstr "NABO_VERSION " nabo\nabo.h
#define NABO_VERSION "1.0.7"
#define NABO_VERSION_INT 10007
```

and got both lines back. Adding `/c:` is necessary:

```
> findstr /c:"NABO_VERSION " nabo\nabo.h
#define NABO_VERSION "1.0.7"
```

Now to write this in CMake:

```
# test.cmake

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
# Script mode, no project() call

execute_process(
    COMMAND findstr "/c:NABO_VERSION " [[nabo\nabo.h]]
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    RESULT_VARIABLE FINDSTR_RESULT
    ERROR_VARIABLE FINDSTR_ERROR
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE FINDSTR_OUT
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)

message(STATUS "FINDSTR_ERROR  = ${FINDSTR_ERROR}")
message(STATUS "FINDSTR_OUT    = ${FINDSTR_OUT}")
message(STATUS "FINDSTR_RESULT = ${FINDSTR_RESULT}")
```

Running this script returns the expected result:

```
>cmake -P test.cmake
-- FINDSTR_ERROR  =
-- FINDSTR_OUT    = #define NABO_VERSION "1.0.7"
-- FINDSTR_RESULT = 0
```

This works because, as the `findstr /?` output says:

> Use spaces to separate multiple search strings unless the argument is prefixed with `/C`.

So then you just need the quotes in CMake to ensure the space is included in the *whole* argument.