# How to count lines all text file in a directory and subfolders

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, window, nested-loops

I'm trying to improve a script posted by @Tony in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664761/how-to-count-no-of-lines-in-text-file-and-store-the-value-into-a-variable-using)

> ```
>   @Echo off
>   Set _File=file.txt
>   Set /a _Lines=0
>   For /f %%j in ('Type %_File%^|Find "" /v /c') Do Set /a _Lines=%%j
>   Echo %_File% has %_Lines% lines.
> ```

To count lines all text file in a directory and subfolders:

```
  @Echo off
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  Set _Dir=C:\TEST_DIR\
  Set /a _Lines=0
  for /R %_Dir% %%f in (*.*) do (
    for /f %%j in ('Type !%%f!^|Find "" /v /c') Do Set /a _Lines=!_Lines!+!%%j!
  )
  Echo %_Dir% has %_Lines% lines.
  pause
```

But I'm geting error: "Missing operand."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I'm was using extra `!!` in the sentence:

```
Do Set /a _Lines=!_Lines!+!%%j!
```

This is the working code:

```
@Echo off
Set _Dir=C:\TEST_DIR\
Set /a _Lines=0
for /R %_Dir% %%f in (*.*) do (
  for /f %%j in ('Find "" /v /c ^< "%%~f"') Do Set /a _Lines=_Lines+%%j
)
Echo %_File% has %_Lines% lines.
pause
```

[EDITED] as @aschipfl sugested

Comment: `Type !%%f!` does not make any sense, because this would treat the content of `%%f` (an iterated file) as a variable, which woud be expanded due to the surrounding `!!`, which will most likely result in an empty string; it should read `Type "%%~f"`. Alternatively, replace the entire portion `Type "%%~f"^|Find "" /v /c` by `Find "" /v /c ^< "%%~f"` (this is the way I would actually do it in order to avoid the pipe `|`).

Comment: Since you are not using delayed expansion any more, you do no longer need to enable it...

Answer (score -1):

I see a few problems.

First, as you just discovered while I was typing this, you were getting the missing operand because you were using delayed expansion on `!%%j!`, which you don't need. You also don't need it on `Type !%%f!...`. In fact, as it is, it won't work with files that have spaces. I recommend changing it to `Type "%%~f"...` to allow for spaces in the filename.

In general, you can discover these problems by using `echo` to see how the command is being interpreted. For example, duplicate this line, insert an `echo` after the `Do`. The problem becomes apparent.

```
for /f %%j in ('Type !%%f!^|Find "" /v /c') Do echo Set /a _Lines=!_Lines!+!%%j!
```

Also, beware that you'll probably get unexpected results if you use this on binary files. Consider using a different file mask (or set of file masks) instead of `*.*` in your `for /r` line. For example:

```
for /R %_Dir% %%f in (*.txt *.xml *.ini) do (
```

Comment: The exclamation marks around `%%j` in the `Set /a _Lines=!_Lines!+!%%j!` command line need to be removed also. Actually delayed expansion could be avoided when changing the syntax to `Set /a _Lines=_Lines+%%j` or even to `Set /a _Lines+=%%j`...

Comment: Regarding your first comment, aren't we saying the same thing? Agreed on the second comment.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't read carefully enough, sorry... I actually don't understand why you received a down-vote...