# find /C "A" results in "find: 'A': No such file or directory"

Tags: windows, cmd, findstr

I am trying to count lines in a file following [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664761/how-to-count-no-of-lines-in-text-file-and-store-the-value-into-a-variable-using), e.g. using `find /C`, but all I see in console is:

```
find: '/C': No such file or directory
find: 'A': No such file or directory
```

I have a simple "TEST.txt" file with three As and three Bs, all in new lines:

```
$ type TEST.txt
A
A
A
B
B
B
```

findstr seems to work, but it cannot return counts:

```
$ type TEST.txt | findstr "A" 
A                             
A                             
A
```

find does not work:

```
$ type TEST.txt | find "A"
find: 'A': No such file or directory
```

What am I missing?

PS: The whole example from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664761/how-to-count-no-of-lines-in-text-file-and-store-the-value-into-a-variable-using) does not work as well:

```
$ findstr /R /N "^" TEST.txt | find /C ":"
find: '/C': No such file or directory
find: ':': No such file or directory
```

#### Edit:

As it might be important to understand what is happening: I am using a [ConEmu terminal](https://conemu.github.io/).

Comment: Are you invoking `find` from `cmd.exe` or `powershell.exe`?

Comment: TEST.txt is an existing file? Your exact command `findstr /R /N "^" TEST.txt | find /C ":"` works for me, on a file where I count occurences of "A".

Comment: I used `cmd.exe` by the way. His error looks like something UNIX would return. `powershell.exe` would return `FIND:Parameter format not correct` because syntax is different.

Comment: As far as I understand I am using `cmd.exe` (command `/cmd {Shells::cmd (Admin)}` in FreeCommander XE)...

Comment: And TEST.txt is an existing file... `findstr /R /N "^" TEST.txt | find /C ":"` still returns `find: '/C': No such file or directory` and `find: ':': No such file or directory` for me.

Comment: Also, I am using ConEmu as the terminal, but I believe this should not change the `cmd.exe` behavior...

Comment: As stated in the comment under the @RizkyFakkel answer: it was not the ConEmu itself, but Rtools has apparently a "linux style" find.exe in its folder. Full path to find.exe works, as is the linux's `wc -l`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have the ConEmu binary directory containing find.exe in the PATH before the Windows directory containing find.exe?

If you cannot change the PATH variable, you can specify the full path to the Windows find with %windir%\System32\find.exe.

Comment: RTools did this to me, never expected another find.exe would jump ahead of %windir%\system32 in the PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Windows' commands for `cmd.exe` on a UNIX shell. `find` on UNIX is different from `find` on Windows' shell.

To count lines in a file in linux, use `wc -l /path/to/file`.

If you want to use the Windows CLI, open up `cmd.exe` and use the answer you linked to:

`findstr /R /N "^" <FILENAME> | find /C ":"`

If you want to go a step further and add more options, take a look at [this link](http://brett.batie.com/scripting/count-number-of-lines-in-a-file-using-dos/)

Comment: I am even more puzzled now... I am opening a `cmd.exe` using Windows start menu, `cmd.exe` opens in ConEmu, which I believed was only a "handy windows terminal" allowing for copying, pasting etc., and `findstr /R /N "^" TEST.txt | find /C ":"` does NOT work, but `wc -l TEST.txt` does...

Comment: Do you have the ConEmu binary directory containing find.exe in the PATH before the Windows directory containing find.exe? I admit that I do not know ConEmu, but just a guess.

Comment: Good guess @lit! It was not the ConEmu itself, but Rtools had find.exe, with the full path to Windows one the `findstr /R /N "^" TEST.txt | C:\Windows\System32\find.exe /C ":"` worked like a charm. `where find` did the job here. Please post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Rizky Fakkel, +1 for you for adding a bit of background to the problem! I am accepting @lit answer as a solution as it directly solved it, but your input is also valuable here.