# How to import extra-large Excel file into Stata?

Tags: excel, stata

I want to open an Excel file with more than 40 GB in Stata, and I used the following command

```
import delimited "F:\US_TradeMatrix_Part2_ST202109291458_v1.csv ", encoding(UTF-8) clear
```

but I can't open and edit the Excel file. I'm wondering how to open this kind of super-large file in Stata?

Comment: Does GM mean GB? How many rows and columns in the dataset? What version of Stata are you using?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1676855-how-to-import-extra-large-excel-file-into-stata

Comment: I'm sorry, the size of the Excel is more than 40GB. There are 10 columns in the datasets, but I don't know the number of rows as the total number of rows exceeds the number of rows displayed by Excel. I'm using Stata 15.

Comment: I think you are saying that you have a .csv file too big to fit into Excel. If so, it is not best described as an Excel file!  But you should be able to find out how many rows it has. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664761/how-to-count-no-of-lines-in-text-file-and-store-the-value-into-a-variable-using .