# GET php data to a commandline prompt

Tags: php, mysql, cmd

A PHP application on the server is saving a certain document with a sequential number into a MySQL database. How to obtaion that sequential number to a command line prompt that initiates the local doocument scanner?

ex:

c:\myscan ask_for_current_seq_nmbr.pdf

myscan is something written in c that takes care of the PC stuff. Only the name of file is unknown.

Some code (from the query PHP file)

```
$query = "SELECT last_seq FROM seq_table WHERE cat = 1";

$result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die('ERROR: '. mysql_error().'<br />ON LINE: '.__LINE__);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['last_seq'];
}
```

!!! NOTE !!!
I am fetching a page from a remote server. ex. www.site.com/query.php?q=SELECT * FROM...
And that selection results in the last used sequential number which I would like to use in my command prompt.

!! UPDATE !!

We HAVE to go through a PHP file on the remote server to avoid having to use Remoote MySQL which has to be enabled on an IP basis.

Comment: Does `$row['last_seq']` contains what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes. It does contain what I am looking for.

Comment: I am now doing this via URLProtocol

Answer (score 1):

You can call processes that run on the commandline with various function from PHP from the [`exec` family<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php).

If you're having problems building the actual command string, you can do with:

```
$cmd = sprintf('c:\myscan %d.pdf', $sequential_number);
```

As you write that the script is already writing it into the db with the `$sequential_number` I assume you have it already.

In case the database generates the number, then probably as the primary key. See [`mysql_insert_id`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) for obtaining the id.

Answer (score 0):

Okay judging by the backslash and the C:\ I am guess you're using windows.

You are going to have to combine the following:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html

[How to store the result of a command expression in a variable using bat scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427218/how-to-store-the-result-of-a-command-expression-in-a-variable-using-bat-scripts)

and then to access the content of the variable you created use the %VARIABLE_NAME% syntax.

Comment: Very good, very good. But we have to go through a  PHP file on the server to avoid using remote MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You should have flag in your mysql table like is_processed with value = 0 or 1.
When scan starts it runs query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE where is_processed = 0 order by sec_number
```

After processing you should run query:

```
UPDATE TABLE set is_processed = 1 where sec_number = 'sec_processed_number';
```

Comment: I am not sure how this relates to what I am trying to do. The trick is to obtain the last used seq number to the command line on the pc.