# batch that return drive letter of USB with specific volume name

Tags: batch-file

I do not have much experience with batch an d need a help with batch script.
Task is, return drive letter as parameter to  %disk_letter%

Idea is use this for search:

WMIC LogicalDisk Where VolumeName='MY_USB' Get /Format:list | FIND "Caption="

I have "Caption=G:" as the result. I need that %disk_leter% parameter was equal just "G:"
Need help to finish this script.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

On Linux right now but here's what I think you'll need to do. Part 1: save the result of your `FIND` command to a variable, and 2: take a substring of the variable. The second part is simple, so I'll start with that (assuming that in the first step you named your variable `var`

```
@echo %var:~-2%
```

That's about as far as I'm comfortable in batch, so this next bit is cobbled together:

To store the result of your find as a variable, try amending your code to:

```
set cmd="WMIC LogicalDisk Where VolumeName='MY_USB' Get /Format:list | FIND "Caption=" "

FOR /F %%i IN (' %cmd% ') DO SET var=%%i
```

and then (remember above) output it with:

```
@echo %var:~-2%
```

The related question from which I am cobbling together the second part is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427218/how-to-store-the-result-of-a-command-expression-in-a-variable-using-bat-scripts) so if this doesn't work as expected I would jump over to that one first.

Comment: @user1615760 Great! You'll want to mark the answer as accepted then to let other people who find this in the future know the solution given actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes...

```
@echo off

for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 " %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk get caption^,description^,drivetype 

2^>NUL`) do (

if %%l equ 2 (
echo %%i is a USB drive.
)
)
```