# Variable initialization issue in batch script

Tags: batch-file, variable-initialization

I have written below script:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Collect source filenames from C:\Files and load into C:\doc.txt
dir C:\sources\Sourcefiles /b /a-d > C:\sourcefilenames.txt

REM fetch count of source files and store into variable count
For /F  %%I in ('call C:\count.bat ') Do Set count=%%I

REM loop "count" number of times and echo temp.txt value
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%count%) DO (

REM call line.bat to fetch line 1,line 2 and so on of sourcefilenames.txt    for each loop
call line.bat %%A>C:\temp.txt

set /p var=<C:\temp.txt
echo var:%var%    ----------> returns previous run value
type C:\temp.txt  ----------. returns current value of temp.txt

)
```

Basically what i am trying to do out of the above script is:
I am creating a variable(var) from the content of temp.txt(data in temp.txt will change for each time loop runs) to be used in multiple loops.

But the problem i am facing is :
Echo var is:%var% command returning me previous run value not temp.txt current content.whereas command "type C:\temp.txt" returning me temp.txt current content.
(Note: if i have called/created variable "var" from some other script it returns me that previous value else it returns Null)

Your help/guidance on above issue is really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: you have a [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) problem. Use `echo var:!var!`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the variable remains in memory, without being re-read.Attempts to limit the validity of the variable.
setlocal 
echo something..... 
endlocal 
or  @echo off & setlocal

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Actually i am beginner to Batch scripting.. So could you please edit the script as required and share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

When CMD.exe encounters a block of code in parentheses, it reads and parses the entire block before executing.  This can cause unintuitive behavior.  In this case, your `echo var:%var%` line is being parsed once at the beginning of the loop and never again.

The easiest fix for this is to change that line to

```
echo var:!var!
```

The `!var!` syntax is parsed every time through the loop.  This works because you have `enabledelayedexpansion` set in your script.

Another workaround to this type of problem is to remove the parentheses and instead call out to a subroutine.

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%count%) DO call :loopLineBat %%A
... rest of script
exit /b

:loopLineBat
 >%temp%\temp.txt call line.bat %1

<%temp%\temp.txt set /p var=
echo var:%var%
type %temp%\temp.txt
exit /b
```

This loop does the same as above, but because it is not in a parenthesized block, all of the lines are parsed and executed in order.

Comment: Thanks Stephan & Ryan.. I tried both of the work around & it worked perfectly as i was looking for.. Thanks buddy..

Comment: Hi Guys, I have one more query. Can you please clarify. I want to store output of below script into a variable. findstr /R /N "^"  C:\Users\Sunaj\Desktop\batch_script\doc.txt  | find /C ":" I tried to use ------ For /F  %%I in ('findstr /R /N "^"  C:\Users\Sunaj\Desktop\batch_script\doc.txt  | find /C ":"') Do Set var=%%I ----- But seems like due to double quote this above script was not working. Please suggest

Comment: @Sunaj See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1427511 .  If that doesn't help, feel free to [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).