# How to fetch single file name from folder using their extension without using for loop in shell script?

Tags: shell, batch-file

I want to fetch single file from one specific folder, the folder contains only single file , so don't want to use for loop for that . how can I write batch script for that . Below is my sample code but its uses for loop, and i think if their is only single file then why we use for loop.

```
cd ${p:DownloadArtifacts}\ReleaseNote
for %%# in (*.xlsx) do echo myvalue=%%~nx#
```

and one more script is

```
dir /s /p /b "*.xlsx
```

using this script i cant store the value into variable , please help..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store the result of a command expression in a variable using bat scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427218/how-to-store-the-result-of-a-command-expression-in-a-variable-using-bat-scripts) and [Set output of a command as a variable (with pipes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952295/set-output-of-a-command-as-a-variable-with-pipes)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and/or risk a look into Jon Skeet's [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). You are always welcome to ask, but please keep the above in mind. :)

Comment: The best way to get the output of a command to a variable is a `for /f` loop. But even better is it to use the `for` in the first place. *Why* don't you want to use `for`?

Comment: a technically correct answer would be_ `dir /s /p /b "*.xlsx >out.txt` and `<out.txt set /p filename=`, but it involves a (temporary) file, which makes that a worse choice than the `for` loop.

Comment: You say a "file from one specific folder". Why then use `dir` switch `/s` and even `/p`?

Answer (score 1):

By saying  *"from one specific folder, the folder contains **only single file**"* why even do all this fancy stuff?

Assuming you are using `copy` to copy the file:

```
cd to dir...
copy /Y *.xlsx "C:\some directory"
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see no reason whatsoever for wanting to do this without a loop!

The only way I can think of without the use of a temporary holding file would be using `ForFiles`. *However `ForFiles` is technically a looping command in its own right*.

To do it you'd need to run the original script from itself, *which I suppose could be termed looping too*!

Here it is though, just for the hell of it:

```bat
@Echo Off
If Defined me GoTo :Next
Set "me=%~f0"
ForFiles /M *.xlxs /C "Cmd /C 0x220x22%me%0x22 @file0x22"
Exit /B
:Next
Set "var=%~1"
Rem show variable
Set var
Pause
```